# Android - can no longer see google Maps after going to production

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

All,

I have been banging my head over this one for a few weeks now.  I got google maps v2 setup for debug following all of their directions.  I got my debug key based on the debug.keystore and everything worked great.

I was then releasing my application to the Google Play Store and followed the instructions on how to generate my release key and I generated my Google API Key using the Sha1 of the release key as the instructions state.

I released my application to the store and everything works great.  Here is the problem though, I can no longer get the maps to show up even when switching back to the debug API key.

Currently to debug I have been releasing a build to Beta, waiting 3 hours, and then fixing accordingly.  Luckily my map work has stabilized on this application but I would still like to understand what is going on.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that before you release to actually build apk in production mode then do adb install to your device. I try it and see if it works. At least it guarantee working before putting it up 
Make sure that the map key id you use in the manifest is for release mode not debug mode.

Comment: Thanks Snake.  I am still a noob on Android and didn't realize I could install the apk directly.  Thanks for the tip.  I would still like to figure out how to re-enable the map in debug mode.

Comment: When you are in debug mode, then you have to revert back to the debug key.

Answer (score 1):

Just before exporting the app as apk, replace the Google Maps debug key with release key. It worked for me.

**Debug certificate:** The Android SDK tools generate this certificate automatically when you do a "debug" build from the command line, or when you build and run a project from Eclipse without exporting it as a released application. The certificate is only for use with an application that you're testing; you can't publish an app that's signed with a debug certificate. The debug certificate is described in more detail in the section Signing in Debug Mode in the Android Developer Documentation. You can generate an API key from this certificate, but only use the key for testing, never for production.

**Release certificate:** The Android SDK tools generate this certificate when you do a "release" build with either ant program or Eclipse. You can also generate this certificate using the keytool program. This certificate can be used with an app you release to the world. Once you have the correct certificate for your needs, you can display its SHA-1 fingerprint using the keytool program.

More here: [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: Thanks fida1989.  You didn't read my post clearly.  My problem is not getting the map to work to release.  My issue is since I have released I cannot get it to work when debugging anymore and I am swapping the keys when I attempt this.  It still works perfectly in release mode.

Comment: Did you try to debug from a different pc? If yes, then get a new debug key from that pc.